# Media Source API Chrome 33 not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, media-source

The media source API in Google Chrome 33 is not working after I installed the latest Windows 7 updates and rebooted my computer. It was perfectly working before the reboot.

When going [here](https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html) I get the following message: Media Source API is not available.

Chrome Version: Version 33.0.1750.149 m

I have checked chrome://flags/ and nothing has changed in there.

Rebooting my computer several time after that didn't help. (It did once few days ago when I had the same message).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I had to uninstall and install Google Chrome again.